# MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, discord, discord.js, bots

node version: 13

**When I type like !server it gives  me this error:**

```
if (typeof data !== 'string') throw new error(errorMessage);
                              

RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings.
```

I have no idea what to do.

**server-info.js:**

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
    commands: ['serverinfo', 'server-info', 'si', 'server'], // You Can Keep Any Name
    description: 'Gives Info About A Server', // Optional

    callback: (message, args) => {

        const { guild } = message
        const icon = message.guild.iconURL() // Icon Of Server
        const roles = message.guild.roles.cache.map(e => e.toString()) // Roles Of Server
        const emojis = message.guild.emojis.cache.map(e =>  e.toString()) // Emojis Of Server
        const emojicount = message.guild.emojis.cache 
        const members = message.guild.members.cache // Members In Server
        const create = message.guild.createdAt.toLocaleDateString() // Server Create Date 

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setTitle('Server Info')
        .setThumbnail(`${icon}`)
        .addField('Server Onwer:-', guild.owner)
        .addField('Server ID:-', guild.id)
        .addField('Server Creation Date:-', create)
        .addField('Boost Count:-', guild.premiumSubscriptionCount)
        .addField('Boost Level:-', guild.premiumTier)
        // You Can Add Any Emoji
        .addField('Member Count:-', `${members.size}\n${members.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size}(Human)\n${members.filter(member => member.user.bot).size}(BOT)`)
        .addField('Mmeber Stats:-', `${guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status == 'online').size}:-\n${guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status == 'idle').size}:-\n${guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status == 'dnd').size}:-\n${guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status == 'offline').size}:-⚫\n`)
        .addField('Highest Role:-', guild.roles.highest)
        .addField('Roles:-', `${roles}`, true) // <true> Means All Roles Will Come In Line
        .addField('Emoji Count:-', `${emojicount.size}\n${emojicount.filter(emoji => !emoji.animated).size}(Non Animated)\n${emojicount.filter(emoji => emoji.animated).size}(Animated)`)
        .addField('Emojis:-', `${emojis}`, true) // <true> Means All Emojis Will Come In Line // This Will All Emojis Of Server
        // You Can Add Any Emoji
        .addField('Server Stats:-', `${guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type == 'text').size}⌨️\n${guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type == 'voice').size}\n${guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type == 'news').size}\n${guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type == 'category').size}`)
        .setFooter('Server Info', icon)
        // Add More Fields If You Want, I Have Added Main One's
        message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too when started coding on djs v13 instead of v12.5.3!
This is not really proper way of fixing this problem but you can try adding `'** **' + your_value` in every `.addField`, for me it was a solution.
(Example: `` .addField('Server ID:-', `** **` + guild.id) ``)

Comment: It's now gives me this error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'status')
    at C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\commands\info\server-info.js:28:103

Comment: That is a different problem. This answer solved the problem you had in the question. You can ask another question if you have another problem not related to the problem stated in the question (the question says that embed field values must not be empty put the error you put in the comment is originating from below)